# I can't compare my date using MomentJs and Vue

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I would like to find if my duration is > 0.  I use MomentJs and Vue to get my duration using this code :

```
 moment3: function (date) {
  var now = moment();
  var day = moment(date);
  var duration = day.diff(now);
   return parseInt(duration);
  },
```

I get the duration correctly (2987546325 in example). But still this code not working.

```
<a v-if="event.time | moment3 > 0"> Do somethingHere </a>
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: And with something like that `"(event.time | moment3) > 0"` ?

Comment: Still not working..

Comment: If you add `{{ event.time | moment3 }}` into your HTML, have you the right value ? (value > 0)

Comment: Yes. 256988458 in example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're trying to use `moment3` as a Vue filter function.

There are two problems here:

1. You can't use a filter function in a `v-if` expression. They're only available inside a `{{ ... }}` or a `v-bind` expression.
2. You can't put anything after a filter function, other than the function's arguments or another filter function. So the `> 0` isn't allowed even if you were in a `{{ ... }}` or `v-bind`.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

The `|` character will just be interpreted as JavaScript's bitwise OR operator in this case.

You'd probably be better off just using a method instead. So define `moment3` inside your component's `methods` and then call it using `v-if="moment3(event.time) > 0"`.